# How can I mock a singleton class with NSubstitute?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mocking, nsubstitute

I have a Singleton class, something like this :

```
public class XConnector : IXConnector
        {

            private static readonly Lazy<XConnector> instance = 
                    new Lazy<XConnector>(() => new XConnector());

            public static XConnector Instance => instance.Value;

            private XConnector()
            {
            }

            public async Task<XConnector> GetData(XConnector con)
            {
            }
      }
```

How can I mock this class with NSubstitute ?

in other hand : I want something like this

```
var target = Substitute.For<IXConnector>();
```

this is a quick Watch when I debug this code

[image]
 any help is welcome.

Comment: And what´s the problem? `Substitute.For<IXConnector>();` should perfectly work if `IXConnector` is an interface (what I suppose).

Comment: You can use Mark Seemann's Ambient Context pattern. This will allow you to inject an instance while still providing the intent of the Singleton.

Comment: @HimBromBeere test this code..and see in _target field, you'll see that's null

Comment: You need a proxy for `IXConnector`, but in tne watch `target` is of type `ICrmConnectorProxy`.

Comment: @HimBromBeere can you post your solution please ?

Comment: @DavidOsborne I dont see how can I do it, give me an exemple please.

Comment: How does `CrmConnector` rely on `XConnector`?

Comment: Anyway I think the `__target`-member is not what you think it is (not sure on the internal implementation however). Just work with the code `var target = Substitute.For<IXConnector>();` you allready have. This will give you a proxy-instance of your interface. However it doesn´t know *anything* of your singleton. Maybe yoou should show how you´re using the mock.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I've fixed, CRMconnector is a typing error. Normally it is XConnector

Comment: @HimBromBeere all the problem is there [Just work with the code var target = Substitute.For<IXConnector>();] . of corse I have to work with it. the question is how to mock a singleton..

Comment: There *is no* singleton, just an instance of an interface involved. So show what you´re doing with `target`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't remember the implementation of the Ambient Context pattern, I don't have the book to hand. However, it would look something like this:

```
public class XConnector : IXConnector
{
    private static IXConnector _instance = new XConnector();

    private XConnector()
    {
    }

    public static IXConnector Current
    { 
       get
       {
           return _instance;
       }
       set 
       {
           // Think about thread-safety
           // Check for null?
           _instance = value;
       }
    }

    public async Task<XConnector> GetData(XConnector con)
    {
    }
}
```

Then your test can do this:

```
XConnector.Current = Substitute.For<IXConnector>();
```

Your functional code can do this, working with the default instance, or the fake one:

```
XConnector.Current.GetData(...);
```

Comment: You put me on the right path. But I do not think I have my answer. Because the instance is a readonly

Comment: Is that essential? If you want to replace the instance with a fake, you're going to need some way to set it and the current design rules out a constructor.